# windows phone 8.1 attach windbg to a build in process

Tags: debugging, windows-phone, windbg, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to know how to attach windbg to a process running in windows phone 8.1. Googling didn't help. Can anybody help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Connect WinDbg to an existing process on the phone

`1.` In TShell, enter this command:

debug-device –debugger WinDbgPath

where WinDbgPath is the path to WinDbg on the host computer.

`2.` Example:

```
debug-device –debugger “C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\WinDbg.exe”
```

`3.` In WinDbg, on the File menu, choose Attach to Process. Select one of the listed            processes, and click OK.

For more Refrence [Use debug-device in TShell to attach a debugger to a process](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-US/OEM/docs/Phone_Testing/Use_debug-device_in_TShell_to_attach_a_debugger_to_a_process)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've read that TShell is only available for registered OEM users.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use windbg to attach to a process running on a WP8.1 device or emulator (which is really a virtual machine and so for all intents and purposes is a different machine) using the public tools. Microsoft may have internal tools for this but IF they do they're not available.

You haven't said what you're trying to achieve but you'll probably need to use the Performance and Diagnostics tools (via debug menu) to get the information you need.
For more see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/03/performance-profiling-on-windows-phone-8-1-with-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to see how Office for example handles a file i provide.

Comment: @user3640195 In future, if you're working with the OEM tools I would expect you'll get a faster/better response to future questions from the private mailing lists for such development than here where we primarily discuss public tools/SDKs. It will also help you get better answers if you make it clear that you're doing something with specific, private, tools when asking your question.

Comment: Actually i am not working with OEM tools...but it seems that this is the only solution for my issue. I'll have to register for an OEM account.

Comment: Also it seems that Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2013 cannot be installed in wp 8.1 either.

Comment: @user3640195 registering as an OEM is what you would do if you were building phones yourself. If you're just developing apps it's not what you want or need. Why do you need to know what Office does with the files it opens?

Comment: i am writing a file fuzzer for my masters' thesis and i need a debugger attached to the launched process.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect that device using USB-EEM. 
Then you can connect windbg for that device by below methods on host:
1. open windbg.
2 go to file-> kernel dbug
3.skip port number, enter the key value as 1.2.3.4.
Then restart your device.
will connnect to your device.